# Doctrine findOneBy(), foreign key value is empty

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am making blog maker in Symfony and Doctrine

I am trying to connect, ID of row in blog posts with comments by `blog_id` value, but when I query some blog posts with `findOneBy()`, the comments in that post are empty even when I have some entries in database.

Dump

[image]

\Entity\BlogPosts.php

```
class BlogPosts
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Frontend\Blog\Fe_blog_comments", mappedBy="blogId")
     */
    private $comments;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    //...
}
```

\Entity\Frontend\Blog\Fe_blog_comments.php

```
class Fe_blog_comments
{
    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\BlogPosts", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="blog_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $blogId;

    //...
}
```

EDIT:
Query from controller

```
$postContent = $entityManager->getRepository(BlogPosts::class)
            ->findOneBy(
                array('postLink' => $link));
dump($postContent->getComments());
```

Profiler doctrine query:

```
SELECT 
  t0.id AS id_1, 
  t0.author_id AS author_id_2, 
  t0.post_time AS post_time_3, 
  t0.edit_time AS edit_time_4, 
  t0.post_content AS post_content_5, 
  t0.post_title AS post_title_6, 
  t0.post_extract AS post_extract_7, 
  t0.post_status AS post_status_8, 
  t0.post_link AS post_link_9, 
  t0.meta_description AS meta_description_10, 
  t0.meta_keywords AS meta_keywords_11 
FROM 
  blog_posts t0 
WHERE 
  t0.post_link = ? 
LIMIT 
  1
```

Comment: Is the dump a result of the `getComments()` method? Or are you directly dumping `$this->comments`?

Comment: The profiler will show you the query executed. Can you show us that query? You most likely have some sort of SQL mis-join, so you do not get any comments.

Comment: `initialized => false` -> Have you tried doing a `$post->getComments()` so that related objects are fetched and initialized from DB? Possibly add a `fetch="EAGER"` on your `BlogPost#comments` property to automagically fetch them at fetch-time of the `BlogPost` instead of initializing them later. (if they're something you always want to load when viewing the post, be mindful of performance hits on index pages)

Comment: Also, inspect using a debugger, e.g. xdebug in PhpStorm. If you break the code execution you can simply "inspect" and "evaluate" the concerned objects and do execute a `$blogPost->getComments()` on the spot to see what the result of that would be, then and there, instead of dumping and F5'ing till you see blue in the face.

Comment: I edit the question and add query that I using

Comment: @rkeet Adding `fetch="EAGER"` to `BlogPost#comments` resolve this problem.

Comment: @Marek please do not add eager fetching blindly. Your comments will be there when you start using your collection (i.e. iterate over it), dumping it will not trigger loading objects from the database.